# How do I code this pattern with 2 loops only?

Tags: c

```
    *

  * * *

* * * * *

  * * *

    *
```

This is the pattern I want to get as an output... I made it with 3 loops, but how do I make it with only 2 loops?

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        for (j = 1; j < 2 * i; j++) {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
                printf("");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }
    else {
        for (j = 1; j <= 2 * (n - i) - 1; j++) {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
                printf("");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here I have two outer for loops for two parts of this pattern. First is for regular triangle, the second is for rotated triangle. How do I make in one outer loop and only one inner loop?

Comment: You can make it with 1 loop even, or no loop at all. What exactly is the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of commenting, code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: This has only two levels of nested loops, isn't this what you wanted? Anyway: It all boils down to getting the correct symbol for some arbitrary coordinate. With one loop iterate through rows and with a nested loop though columns and write a function to determine the symbol at this coordinate.

Comment: Was `printf("");` supposed to be `printf("*");`? Edit yes: [https://ideone.com/H3ce8T](https://ideone.com/H3ce8T)

Comment: Here I have two outer for loops for two parts of this pattern. First is for regular triangle, the second is for rotated triangle. How do I make in one outer loop and only one inner loop? This is what want to get...

Comment: The outer loop can work out the number of `*` to be printed on each row. For example: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {` `stars = 2 * i + 1;` `if (stars > n) stars = 2 * n - stars;`

Answer (score 1):

Let `n` be the length of the pattern (In your sample, n = 9). Then the problem is unclear when `(n / 2) % 2 == 1`, for instance it isn't possible to make the pattern when n = 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  assert((n / 2) % 2 == 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0
       && n / 2 <= (i + j) && (i + j) < 3 * n / 2
       && n / 2 <= (n - 1 - i + j) && (n - 1 - i + j) < 3 * n / 2) {
        printf("*");
      } else {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

N odd,

```
 #define N 5

 for(int i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
      for(int j=0 ; j<N ; j++)
            printf("%s", abs(i-N/2)+abs(j-N/2)<=N/2 ? " *":"  ");
      printf("\n");
 }
```

N = 21

```
                     *                    
                   * * *                  
                 * * * * *                
               * * * * * * *              
             * * * * * * * * *            
           * * * * * * * * * * *          
         * * * * * * * * * * * * *        
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *      
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *    
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *    
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *      
         * * * * * * * * * * * * *        
           * * * * * * * * * * *          
             * * * * * * * * *            
               * * * * * * *              
                 * * * * *                
                   * * *                  
                     *
```

Comment: If an extra empty line is (really?) needed after each row, just add an `\n` to the 2nd printf.